# conceptual schema

Tags: database-design

I need to check if I have the correct conceptual database model. My requirements

1. A club can play more competitions and there can be more teams in the competition
2. The owner, player or coach may not work in more than one team (I assume that this is an integrity limitation and is not included in the conceptual model)
3. The club must have exactly one owner and exactly one coach (I'm not sure how to implement it here, is it also an integrity restriction?)
4. A team member can act in multiple roles at once

Thank you in advance for all the comments

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your conceptual schema represents what you said, for the most part. I'm assuming `Team` and `Club` are synonymous here. If so, does a `Member` of the `Club` need to be the `Owner` or can it be a non-member?

In any case, you'll need to setup a one-to-one relationship between `Owner` and `Club` (e.g. `Club` would store `OwnerId`). Then a **foreign key constraint** would be setup on the `Club.OwnerId` referencing `Owner.OwnerId` to ensure the referential integrity of your second point.

Typically the **foreign key constraint** will also ensure that the `Club.OwnerId` is non-null, i.e. each `Club` has one `Owner` as part of your third requirement. You'll also want to follow the same **foreign key constraint** on `Club.CoachId` which will either reference a separate `Coach` table or the `MemberId` of the `Members` table, if you don't have a `Coach` table.

If you don't have a separate `Coach` table then you'll need a `IsCoach` boolean based field in your `Member` table, and you should do the same for the `Captain` entity. Instead of a separate table, you can easily store a boolean based field on `Member` called `IsCaptain`. This also allows you to fulfill the multiple roles in your fourth requirement.

Comment: I made a few edits, uploading the image to the original post.

The owner must be a member.
A team member can be an owner or a player or a coach (all together)

Comment: I added a 1: 1 configuration between the club and the owner. 
I start with databases, so I'm not sure if I'm the foreign key, the implementation is correct.
I would like to ask if it doesn't matter that I have an ID with a team member and then again with the owner and the coach?
I use identification dependent member-> owner, so that probably shouldn't be a problem right?

The coach must have his own table, because other functions are linked to this

Comment: @Aaron7 just to clarify, since `Owner` and `Coach` need their own tables, the `Club` would have a **foreign key** reference for `Owner` and another **foreign key** reference for `Coach` to establish referential integrity. You may also need to define the `Club.OwnerId` and `Club.CoachId` as non-nullable columns, to ensure "*exactly one*" of each. It would not store any `MemberId` field though, the `Member` table itself would have a **foreign key** reference to `Club` on `ClubId`. The `Coach` and `Owner` will each have a `MemberId` so they also can have **foreign key** references to `Member`.

Comment: There should be no problems in doing any of that.